# PHP Google People API save() not working anymore

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, google-people-api

We save our contacts from our php application into our Google contacts using `$contact->save();`

This has been working fine until very recently when none of our application contacts are getting updated/saved in Google contacts.

Has Google modified any of its apis that we need to update our code to call the new api/functions? I checked up the documentation but I am unable to find anything.

Code:

```
$googleOAuth2Handler = new GoogleOAuth2Handler(CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SEC,unserialize(SCP), REFRESH_TOKEN); 
$people = new GooglePeople($googleOAuth2Handler);
$contact = $people->get($google_id);
$contact->save(); //This is the function which no longer works, but there is no error thrown.
```

Comment: What library exactly are you using? What’s the error, if any?

Comment: use RapidWeb\GooglePeopleAPI\GooglePeople;
use RapidWeb\GooglePeopleAPI\Contact;
use RapidWeb\GoogleOAuth2Handler\GoogleOAuth2Handler;
use Statickidz\GoogleTranslate;



There is no error at all. Just that Google contacts is not getting updated/created. It was working fine until a few weeks back but suddenly this stopped working.

Comment: Message: { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"parent\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'parent' could not be found in request message.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest", "fieldViolations": [ { "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"parent\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'parent' could not be found in request message." } ] } ] } }

Filename: /home/myhealthconnect/public_html/vendor/rapidwebltd/php-google-people-api/src/GooglePeople.php

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue, I'm getting the same error. please check my question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75634127/google-peopleapi-created-contact-not-saved-or-synced-in-google-contacts?noredirect=1#comment133472687_75634127