# Google PeopleAPI: Created contact not saved or synced in Google Contacts

Tags: google-api

I am using the Google People API to create a new contact in Google Contacts but it is not saved or synced in Google Contacts.
I'm not getting any errors.

Here is the code I am using to create the contact:

```
$client = new GoogleClient(config('google'));
$googleClient = $client->getClient();
$peopleService = new PeopleService($googleClient);

$newContact = new \Google\Service\PeopleService\Person();
$newContact->setNames([new Google_Service_PeopleService_Name(['givenName' => 'John', 'familyName' => 'Doe'])]);
$newContact->setEmailAddresses([new Google_Service_PeopleService_EmailAddress(['value' => 'johndoe@example.com'])]);

$respose = $peopleService->people->createContact($newContact);
dd($respose); // it rerurns respose of person
```

The $newContact variable contains the newly created contact's resource name. I have also tried requesting a sync for the connection, as follows:

```
    $client = new GoogleClient(config('google'));
    $googleClient = $client->getClient();
    $peopleService = new PeopleService($googleClient);

    $params = [
        'personFields' => 'metadata,names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers',
        'pageSize' => 2000,
        'requestSyncToken' => true
    ];

    $fullSyncResponse = $peopleService->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', $params);
    while ($fullSyncResponse->getNextPageToken() != null) {
        $fullSyncResponse = $peopleService->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', [
            'personFields' => 'metadata,names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers',
            'pageSize' => 2000,
            'requestSyncToken' => true,
            'pageToken' => $fullSyncResponse->getNextPageToken()
        ]);
    }

    // Fetch incremental changes using the sync token returned in the last fullSyncResponse.
    // try {
        $incrementalSyncResponse = $peopleService->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', [
            'personFields' => 'metadata,names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers',
            'pageSize' => 2000,
            'syncToken' => $fullSyncResponse->getNextSyncToken()
        ]);

        if ($incrementalSyncResponse->getConnections() != null)
            foreach ($incrementalSyncResponse->getConnections() as $person) {
                $this->handlePerson($person);
            }

        while ($incrementalSyncResponse->getNextPageToken() != null) {
            $incrementalSyncResponse = $peopleService->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', [
                'personFields' => 'metadata,names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers',
                'pageToken' => $incrementalSyncResponse->getNextPageToken(),
                'pageSize' => 2000,
                'syncToken' => $fullSyncResponse->getNextSyncToken()
            ]);

            if ($incrementalSyncResponse->getConnections() != null)
                foreach ($incrementalSyncResponse->getConnections() as $person) {
                    $this->handlePerson($person);
                }
        }

        dd($fullSyncResponse, $incrementalSyncResponse); // it rerurns respose of listPeopleConnections
    // } catch (\Exception $ex) {}

public function handlePerson(PeopleService\Person $person)
    {
        if ($person->getMetadata()->getDeleted()) {
            // Handle deleted person
        } else {
            // Handle changed person
        }
    }
```

However, the contact is still not saved or synced in Google Contacts.

Can anyone please advise on what might be causing this issue, and how I can get the newly created contact to be saved and synced in Google Contacts? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Google contacts where?

Comment: It doesn't store the contact on google contacts. but I will show created contact using the listPeopleConnections method of google API SDK.

$list = $peopleService->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', $params);

this code "Prints the created contacts, but it is not synced or saved in google contacts"

Comment: Is anyone there to help?

Comment: When you mention that "the contact gets created successfully", how are you confirming that? Do you get any error on your script? Also, what is the expected behavior, to see it listed in contacts.google.com?

Comment: $list = $peopleService->people_connections->listPeopleConnections('people/me', $params);

see above the code. I got the response of creating people using Google People API. That's why I said that "people created successfully". But It wasn't showing in contacts.google.com. I don't have any single error message when running the code. Please check my code above. Do you have any solution to save contacts on contacts.google.com, that would be helpful.

Comment: Is anyone here to answer for me?